# css not getting applied due to external css inclusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

I am designing application in phonegap.

I have externally included following css:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

In design i want body to have one background image.

For that i have done following:

```
<style>
            /*this block should go in the styles.css file*/
        .ui-panel-inner {
            padding:0px; /*make the buttons flush edge to edge*/
        }
        .ui-controlgroup {
            margin:0; /*make the buttons flush to the top*/
        }
        #header {
            height:54px;
        }
        #bars-button {
            margin:7px;
        }

        .bodyCSSBG
        {
background-image:url("ProjectImages/aboutUsBackground.JPG");
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            background-size:cover;
        }


    </style>
```

In body:

```
<body class="bodyCSSBG">
```

But background image is not getting aaplied to page.

If i remove external css as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
```

Then background image gets applied.

What can i do in this case??

**EDIT1:**

written !Important as:

[image]

Comment: Give `!important` to your style like: `background-image:url("ProjectImages/aboutUsBackground.JPG") !important;`.

Comment: @SujataChanda still not getting applied

Comment: From your screenshot it seems that you need to give a space before `!important`.

Comment: @SujataChanda yes i given the space..but still the same

Answer (score 1):

Use

**!important**

```
.bodyCSSBG
    {
 background-image:url("ProjectImages/aboutUsBackground.JPG") !important;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size:cover;
    }
```

Comment: still not getting applied

Comment: Try to change the order of calling css.
Call <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
first

Answer (score 0):

Is the  tag in the External CSS? If so, there is no need for a  tag.

In External CSS Files you just write the CSS

Answer (score 0):

What is sequence of adding css files. Make sure to include your CSS at end to overwritten changes you have done in your custom CSS.